# Get parameter with the character '#' from a query string on java

Tags: java, servlets, query-string, http-request

I am trying to get a request string that has the character `#` and my parameter is got only until the `#`. But the thing is that I need to have this character, can't remove it.

Any idea?

Comment: `#` is the fragment identifier.  If it's part of a parameter in the query string, you must url encode the query string first.  If you just want to get the fragment, I'm sure whatever wrapper you are using can do it in a similar fashion as getting the query string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Encode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) the # if it has to be there. A literal # indicates a [fragment id](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5) and can't be used in a URI for any other purpose. w3schools has [encoding tables](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) so you can look up the values yourself, too.

Comment: Right, works perfectly! **URLEncode** and **URLDecode**. I didn't want to use it because the part of the system that generates it is supposed to be the most general as possible and not all the data will be url. But there's no problem to encode all data. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the parameter value correctly.

If the URL is generated by a JSP, make sure to use the JSTL `c:url` tag:

```
<c:url value="/path/to/myServlet">
    <c:param name="param1" value="#paramValue"/>
</c:url>
```

If you're using straight Java, use `URLEncoder.encode()`.

If the URL is static, use `%23paramValue` instead of `#paramValue`